# fgets is ignored, and problem passing value into an array of structures

Tags: c

I am attempting to create a function which reads the personal details of a person and pass the data to the calling function via a structure, then return the number of names returned.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100
int readin(Employee *emp);
int main()
{
  Employee emp[MAX];
  int size;
  size = readin(emp);
  return 0;
}
int readin(Employee *emp)
{
  char name[40], tel[40], *p;
  int id,size=0,i=0;
  double sal;
  printf("Enter name:\n");
  scanf("\n");
  fgets(name,40,stdin);
  if (p=strchr(name,'\n')) *p = '\0';
  if (strcmp("#",name) != 0) {
    while (strcmp("#",name) != 0) {
      strcpy(emp->name, name);
      printf("Enter tel:\n");
      fgets(tel,40,stdin);
      if (p=strchr(tel,'\n')) *p = '\0';
      strcpy(emp->telno, tel);
      printf("Enter id:\n");
      scanf("%d",id);
      emp->id = id;
      printf("Enter salary:\n");
      scanf("%f",sal);
      emp->salary = sal;
      size++;
      i++;
      printf("Enter name:\n");
      fgets(name,40,stdin);
    }
  }
  return size;
}
```

The structure Employee is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct {
  char name[40];
  char telno[40];
  int id;
  double salary;
} Employee;
```

However, when I execute the program, the first fgets for the name is ignored, and the loop does not stop even when I key in #, which is supposed to indicate termination.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `while (strcmp("#",name) != 0) {` This will never yield true: fgets() retains the (CR)LF in the input string.

Comment: Maybe your environment uses `'\r'` for <ENTER>? Also try `strchr(name, '\r')`...

Comment: The `scanf()` for salary leaves the newline in the input buffer, so the `fgets()` after it reads to the newline.  Don't mix `fgets()` and `scanf()`; use `fgets()` to get the data and `sscanf()` to parse the lines that `fgets()` reads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
if (p=strchr(name,'\n')) *p = '\0';
```

Here, you properly get rid of the newline at the end of your input. However, you only do it before the loop. Thus, when someone enters `#` past the initial input, the trailing newline won't get removed and it will never equal `#`. You should also trim it at the end of the loop:

```c
// last 4 lines of loop
size++;
i++;
printf("Enter name:\n");
fgets(name,40,stdin);
if (p=strchr(name,'\n')) *p = '\0';
// loop ends
```

You also have some unnecessary things, like `scanf("\n")` and the `if` statement around the `while` loop (the while loop just won't run if the condition isn't met, no need for an extra if statement).

Answer (score 1):

As  *wildplasser*  pointed out , `\n` will be added at the end of the `name` .  There is an another way to get rid of `\n` from `name`

```
printf("Enter name:\n");
fgets(name,40,stdin);
name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Please refer this link :[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strcspn-in-c/#:~:text=The%20C%20library%20function%20strcspn,search%20has%20to%20be%20made](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strcspn-in-c/#:%7E:text=The%20C%20library%20function%20strcspn,search%20has%20to%20be%20made).